# Reversing a list of elements by indicator

Tags: python, list

I have a list containing:

```
[1,2,3,4,0,9,8,7,6]
```

and i want to reverse the values in the list based on an indicator which is '0' in the list. Hence, for the elements before the '0', i want them to be reversed. and the element after '0' follows which will get me:

```
[4,3,2,1,0,6,7,8,9]
```

I tried using list[::-1] but it doesn't work if i were to condition it based on that indicator. Would appreciate some help on this.

Comment: why not use list slicing? did you try something more than list[::-1] ?

Comment: Can the zero appear more than once in the list? Can it appear zero times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just split according to position of 0, then reverse both parts, reassemble:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,0,9,8,7,6]
zidx = lst.index(0)
result = lst[zidx-1::-1] + [0] + lst[:zidx:-1]
```

result:

```
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

(the finetuning of the slicing takes some time with reverse+slicing but it avoids to create too many temporary lists)

Answer (score 3):

How about this: use `groupby` to group the list into not-zeroes and zeroes, then reverse each of those groups, then join them all together again.

```
import itertools

def flip(seq):
    return [x for k,v in itertools.groupby(seq, key=bool) for x in reversed(list(v))]

test_cases = (
    [1,2,3,4,0,9,8,7,6],
    [1,2,0,3,4,0,5,6,0],
    [1,2,3]
)

for seq in test_cases:
    print("{} flips into {}".format(seq, flip(seq)))
```

One potential advantage that this has over index-and-slicing based solutions is, it can operate on inputs that have more than one zero, or no zeroes at all.

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6] flips into [4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 0, 5, 6, 0] flips into [2, 1, 0, 4, 3, 0, 6, 5, 0]
[1, 2, 3] flips into [3, 2, 1]
```